# Pass in function or value and always return the value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function that will accept another function that when called it will resolve to a particular type of value or if the value is passed just return that value.

However I can't narrow it down to a value at the end.

```
type Test<T> = (() => T) | T

class List{
    constructor(protected fnOrNumber: Test<number>) {
        //fnOrNumber will sometimes be number or function that returns number
    }

    get list(): number{
        return resolve(this.fnOrNumber)
        // ^^^
        //Type 'Test<number>' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        //Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    }

}

//function to resolve the final value
function resolve<T>(v: T): T{
    if (typeof v === 'function') {
        return v() 
    }
    return v
}
```

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=66&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8MB8UC8UAU2CUm6MBAPrAFDkDGANgIbzxQAyAlogN7lQ9RUD2AO0QAnAK5Vg-EdjAj+wCJIgATKADNBAeREA5MQFsARhBEAuWAmSDDJkagJdezqAHpXmnfuOmoAd1YaGih4fgMIYFZwphMoGx8RKGkNMUFJViEoYAALOmAoEQixEWE421NuXgBfSmcAcwioGnZgfAt4uycXHkLgYsEChH4aADcIbBz2ADpPPXKRPEru9ygAPXWll3cYcGgAcjhEJA7TVD2odjiFKAZ4VjrBOiMaaCks3ag9k5E9qc3nbYfPb4QhlBLnS6Ca63e6PZ6vfjvSCfb6-TY1cgY9zqVLpTJvQqhUavbLQdSsR7BEZ0GhiCDkHFpSKZQnDMYoVDYEYWYg8ro8VjqHCgSD8IUjTAYLB7Rl4wR7Rz-Xi9fpQEYg9GbFUlNWYyj6oA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the implementation of your `resolve` function, the signature `resolve<T>(v: T): T` claims to return whatever type is passed to it; i.e. it says if you pass it a function then it returns a function, according to its declaration.

Since you've already declared a type `Test<T> = (() => T) | T`, we can change the `resolve` function as so:

```js
function resolve<T>(v: Test<T>): T{
    if (typeof v === 'function') {
        return (v as () => T)()
    }
    return v
}
```

We need the type assertion, because `typeof v === 'function'` doesn't narrow to `v: () => T`.

Comment: I've written the `Test` type as a literal representation of what it returns (function->value, or just value) would you wrote it differently?
Why `typeof` line doesn't narrow the type?
It works when I use primitive values or anything other that can be used with `typeof`

Comment: The `Test` type is your input, not your output; you said the output should always be a number (i.e. the plain type `T`), so in that case the output should never be a function. `typeof` does narrow the type, just not to `v: () => T`. It narrows it to `v: (T & Function) | (() => T)`. The type `(T & Function)` isn't specific enough for your purpose, so the type assertion is needed.